# How can a simple Spring Boot app (local filesystem listing REST API) be made thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I am writing a test Spring Boot app and I want to build it to be thread-safe from ground-up. For this question, let's assume app is a simple REST API which returns a list of file and directory names from local OS filesystem where app resides based on specified path (provided by user as GET parameter when invoking the REST API).

I appreciate horizontal scaling could be achieved using containers/kubernates, event/queue based architectures and other such approaches - however I am not interested in using those methods at present (unless you folks suggest this is the only elegant solution to my question). Therefore, please assume platform is JVM running on a single multicore (linux) OS instance/server.

```
@RestController
public class myController {

    FileService fileService;

    /**RestController method to return JSON formatted list of file & directory 
     *names contained within a given path when 
     *http://[server:port]/rest/browse?path=[UserSpecifiedPath] 
     is requested by client**/

    @GetMapping("/rest/browse")
    public List<Java.IO.File> browseFiles(@RequestParam(value="path",required=false) String pathName) {

        return fileService.list(pathName);

    }
}

@Service
public class FileService {

    //Service method to return alphabetically sorted list of non-hidden files & directories
    public List<Java.IO.File> list(String pathName) {

        return Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(new File(pathName).listFiles())
                .parallel()
                .filter(file -> !file.getName()
                        .startsWith("."))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::getName))
                .toArray(File[]::new));
    }
}
```

The code to actually return the sorted list of files & dirs is quite dense and leans on Java's Arrays Collection, as well as a lambda function. I am unfamiliar with the underlying code of the Arrays collection (and how to reason about its functionality) as well as the way the lambda function will interact with it. I am keen to limit the use of synchronized/locking to resolve this issue, as I wish FileService() to be as parallelizable as possible.

```
    My concern is related to FileService:
```

- I have instantiated FileService as a singleton (thanks to Spring
  Boot's default behaviour)
- Spring's Controller/servlet is multithreaded insofar as each request
  has at least one thread
- FileService's use of the Arrays Collection code, together with the
  lambda function does on a **new** IO.File object to populate a
  List not *appear* to me to be atomic
- Therefore, multiple threads representing multiple requests could be
  executing different portions of fileService at once, creating
  unpredictable results
- Even if Spring Boot framework somehow handles this particular issue
  behind the scenes, if I want to add some hitherto unwritten
  additional concurrency to the controller or other part of app in
  future, I will still have a fileService.list that is not thread safe
  and my app will therefore produce unpredictable results due to
  multiple threads messing with the instantiated File object in
  fileService.list()

The above represents my best attempt at reasoning about why my code has problems and is possibly stateful. I appreciate there are gaps in my knowledge (clearly, I could do a deep dive into Arrays Collection and lambda function) and I likely do not fully understand the concept of state itself to an extent and getting my self twisted-up over nothing. I have always found state to be a bit confusing given even supposedly stateless languages must store state *somewhere* (in memory, an application has to store its variables at some point, as they are passed between operations).

### Is my reasoning above correct? How can I write FileService to be stateless?

**EDIT**
To answer my own question based on the answers provided by others, FileService is stateless and therefore thread-safe. The variables on which it operates are either local variables, method parameters or return statements which are all thread safe. When a given thread calls the method, these objects are stored in each *thread's* stack. Even if some of the logic in FileService is not atomic, it does not matter for aforementioned reason.

Comment: Please format your code properly ... to make it easier for humans to read.

Comment: There are also many stateful tools like rsync, and java has watch services for directories. Stateless is still good to have, but if it is just a directory listing at some point in time...

Comment: Also, I can see things that would give compilation errors; e.g. an @Autowired annotation on a local variable, a reference to an undeclared variable.  Please show us real code (that compiles).

Comment: @StephenC I have replaced code with something that should compile (absent imports and maven pom).

Comment: What you have shown in `list` is stateless as the file system access + filter+sort isn't storing intermediate information that another thread could see. But take care as it won't scale well, say if you allow many clients to scan the same folder of 100,000 items at same time.

Comment: @hut_rudder - That's good.  (It turns out that my assumptions about what the code should look like were correct ...)

Comment: @DuncG - not scalable in other ways as you suggest. Would probably look to cache directory structure in a more appropriate storage backend. Furthermore, would not, ultimately, want to use any local storage at all for files to be served scalably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore, multiple threads representing multiple requests could be executing different portions of fileService at once,

Correct.

> creating unpredictable results

No. Each thread has its own method invocation, which has its own local variables, which reference their own objects. Since each thread uses its own objects, threads don't interact at all, and can not possibly interfere with each other's work, making this code trivially thread safe.

Put differently, thread safety issues only arise when several threads use the same object. If they use different objects (or the objects are immutable), the code is trivially thread safe.

> As Spring abstracts away the creation of each new controller object and its own multithreading, I struggled to understand correctly what was going on with respect to threads and method invocation in the controller

By default, a controller is application scoped, so the same controller object will be shared by all threads.

> To put it another way, for each chain of logic emanating out of a Spring Controller, I can basically not concern myself with how per-request threads are behaving.

Not quite. If these threads modify shared objects, you are responsible for synchronizing access. It's just that usually, you will not share any mutable objects, trivially fullfilling this requirement. In your case, the Controller object is shared, but not mutable, while the Lists, Streams, Arrays, and File objects are not shared, so there aren't any mutable shared objects.

However, if you were to optimize the performance of your FileService with an in-memory cache such as

```
@Service
class FileService {
    Map<String, File[]> cache = new HashMap<>(); // danger

    public List<File> list(String pathName) {
        var result = cache.get(pathName);
        if (result == null) {
            result = ...;
            cache.put(pathName, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

all threads would share the same controller object, and the same `FileService`, and therefore the same `Map`, requiring you to synchronize access to the `Map` somehow.

Comment: I think that answers it. As Spring abstracts away the creation of each new controller object and its own multithreading, I struggled to understand correctly what was going on with respect to threads and method invocation in the controller. To put it another way, for each chain of logic emanating out of a Spring Controller, I can basically not concern myself with how per-request threads are behaving. Obviously if I start writing multi-threaded code myself within a Spring MVC app, that would be another matter.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer - that adds super helpful clarification for how Spring's object scoping interacts with my toy example. I am now clear as to precisely why my code  is thread-safe and where my lack of knowledge of JVM concurrency lead to confusion. Namely: 1) A lack of understanding of what Spring is doing by-default under the hood with threads and object scopes (many threads but only a single bean in the case of @Service, @Controller...) and 2) Not knowing that **local**, **return** and **method parameter** variables are *almost* always stored per-thread.

Comment: EDIT [last sentence]: **always** stored per-thread and are **almost always** thread-safe (possibly a "straight" always but I could not think of every permutation).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your reasoning is flawed.  I actually can't see any reason why this is not thread-safe.

> 1. I have instantiated `FileService` as a singleton (thanks to Spring Boot's default behavior)

That doesn't actually impact on thread-safety in this case.

> 2. Spring's Controller/Servlet is multi-threaded insofar as each request has at least one thread.

Well, yes.  There could be multiple threads calling `FileService.list(...)` at the same time, so thread-safety is relevant.

> 3. `FileService`'s use of the `Arrays` Collection code, together with the lambda function does on a new `IO.File` object to populate a `List` not appear to me to be atomic.

The fact that it is not atomic (at a certain level) is not actually relevant.

> 4. Therefore, multiple threads representing multiple requests could be executing different portions of `FileService` at once, creating unpredictable results.

Well ... no.  In fact requests do not interact with the state of `FileService` at all.  Each request has its own state separate from all other simultaneous (or otherwise) requests.

The facts that are relevant to thread-safety as follows:

- The `list` method is not referring to any fields of the `FileService` class, or any other of your domain classes.  Therefore it doesn't share state via instance or static fields.
- The `new File(pathName).listFiles()` fragment creates a *thread confined* `File` object and a *thread confined* array.  We can assume that this is thread-safe.  (The javadocs don't mention it, but there is no reason for `File` to interact with other threads.)

Terminology: a "thread confined" object is an object that only one thread can ever access.  It is "confined" to that thread.

- The `Arrays.stream(...)...collect(...)` is using a *thread confined* `Stream` to create an array.
- The `Stream` uses `parallel()` which potentially involves using other (worker) threads.  However, the stream pipeline downstream is just acting on `File` objects in the stream, so there are no thread-safety concerns there.
- Finally, the `Arrays.asList(...)` is wrapping the array as a *thread confined* `List`.

The key thing here is none of this code is going to share state with another thread.

Since there is no sharing of state between threads, there is no possibility that one thread's actions can affect another other one's behavior.  The thread-confined objects don't need to be thread-safe, because we know that know other threads can access them.

Therefore, this code is thread-safe.

And the `FileService` class is stateless too.  (There is no state associated with an instance of `FileService`.)

---

There is a caveat to the above.  If some other thread was modifying the directory that you are listing with `listFiles()` at the same time as a `list` call was happening, it is not clear what files it would see.  (It is potentially operating specific.)

If it was a hard requirement of your "file service" that `list` should provide a view that represents a point-in-time snapshot, then this code doesn't do that.  But that is a fundamental property of `File.listFiles`, and I don't think there is a way to solve that.

---

Finally, I recommend that you read a good book or take a good course on Java concurrent program.  You need to understand the basics before you can reason about them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Helpful to get this answer as well as the @meriton's, as they both answer my question using differing nomenclature. While I had *Java Concurrency in Practice*  open and was using it as a reference while working through this, I had not read from start to finish (not how my brain learns) - nevertheless, understanding that local variables, method parameters and return objects are all per-thread would have prevented my confusion. I will dig deeper into basics. Thanks for your answer.